# When `volatile` is needed when `longjmp()` is called?

Tags: c, volatile, setjmp

I am trying to make a minimal working example to show when `volatile` is needed. But the following example does not require the `volatile`. Could anybody show an example? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static jmp_buf buf;

int main() {
    volatile int local_var = 1;
    int local_var2 = 10;
    if(!setjmp(buf)) {
        local_var = 2;
        local_var2 = 20;
        longjmp(buf, 1);
    } else {
        printf("%d\n", local_var);
        printf("%d\n", local_var2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./main.exe 
2
20
```

Comment: You cannot in general show that `volatile` is needed by running an example program. It is needed because the standard says so.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the local variable could have changed between the setup-call to `setjmp` and the jump back.

[7.13.2.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.13.2.1p3)

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine249) have state, as of the time the longjmp
>   function was called, except that the values of objects of automatic
>   storage duration that are local to the function containing the
>   invocation of the corresponding setjmp macro that do not have
>   volatile-qualified type and have been changed between the setjmp
>   invocation and longjmp call are indeterminate.

`setjmp` snapshots your registers. If the local variable was in a register and you change the variable after the `setjmp` call, when you jump back it'll have the snapshotted value.

On Linux x86_64 I get outputs `2` (up to date because volatile) and `10` (old value) iff I compile with optimization on.